# define different type child in schema(XSD)

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

beginer to schema definition, I have a tag which creates its child at runtime, so it may be possible that we can have name of children for two sequences i.e.

sequence 1:

```
<task>
<a/>
<b/>
<c/>
<d/>
<e/>
</task>
```

sequence 2:

```
<task>
<g/>
<h/>
<i/>
<d/>
</task>
```

How to define this in XSD. ANY could use but it would not ensure the number children, though i keep it with maxnumber unbouded.

Can we igonre/skip the children with in this tag?

Answer (score 0):

In XSD it will

```
<xs:element name="task">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="d" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="e" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So when you are going to create it, you will know the number of childrens, and the name of each one. You change it in the JAXB class used to generate the XSD and thats all

Comment: NO its not capable even it can have unkown number of children with different name.

Comment: You can develop with an iterator, which you dont need to know the number of elements inside. The name, it will be in the Bean which you are using to manage the element "task" (and their childrens)

Comment: @Ellory this XSD is going to use for only validation purpose. it will validate the a huge number of XML file. which have a tag Task whose children varies XML by XML

Answer (score 0):

it works:

```
  <xs:complexType name="task">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```